# Pine Script Remove information on the side

Tags: pine-script

I have this on the left of my chart because I have 2 indicators at the same time but I don't need these numbers on the left.

Is it possible to remove them?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I don't think its possible to remove that because you have two indicator in one and so the TradingView provide two scales for two indicator.

Comment: OK thanks for your advice.  Have a good day